# Killing task in Node.js

Tags: process, kill

I have an app which require to listen to a port (say 8080). Sometimes when I run it there is already a process which is listning to request on that port.
I have therefore made a piece of Node.js code which finds processes running on a given port by a given command (say node or Phyton).

It finds the PID of the process and using `process.kill` it tries to kill the task before starting a new "server" listning to the port. However it *fails*.

```
var lsof = require('lsof');

var info = "%s \"%s\" (pid:%s) in state \"%s\" running on port %s Launced by %s";
/*
options:
  options.ports = A comma separated list of ports you want to look format ["8001, 8080, 8000"]
  options.command = A comma separated list of task names which have running tasks (on given ports) ["node,Python"]
*/
module.exports = (function(options) {

  // lsof.raw(function(data) {
//   console.log(data);
// });

  options = options || {};
  options.ports = (typeof options.ports !== "undefined") ? options.ports.toString() : "8001, 8080, 8000";
  options.commands = (typeof options.commands !== "undefined") ? options.commands.toString() : "node,Python";

  options.commands = options.commands.split(",");
  options.ports = options.ports.split(",");

  console.log("Will test port(s) %s for task(s) started by %", options.ports, options.commands);

  options.ports.map(function(port) {
    lsof.rawTcpPort(port, function(tasks) {
      console.log("checking port %d found %d tasks started by %s", port, tasks.length, options.commands.join(" or "));
      tasks.filter(function(task) {
          console.log(info, "Found task ", task.name, task.pid, task.state, port, task.command);
          return options.commands.indexOf(task.command) > -1;
        })
        .map(function(task) {
          console.log(info, "Send command SIGINT to task ", task.name, task.pid, task.state, port, task.command);
          process.kill(task.pid, "SIGINT");
        });
    });
  });
})();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any reasons why you can't show the code here? This question is not going to be helpful or make any sense in the future if the gist is deleted!

Comment: There you go @Phorce :-) Code added to question.